# How to find rows that are present in two DataFrames, but with different values on chosen columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say we have two DataFrames, `df1` and `df2` with the same columns:

```
  | Name | Value1 | Value2      | Name | Value1 | Value2
--------------------------   --------------------------
1 | John |    1   |   2       1 | John |    4   |   2   
--------------------------   --------------------------
2 | Sue  |    1   |   2       2 | Sue  |    1   |   3   
--------------------------   --------------------------
3 | Bob  |    1   |   2       3 | Bob  |    5   |   6
```

As we can see, the only difference is for row with `Name` 'John' the column `Value1` changed from 1 to 4, for 'Sue' the columns `Value2` changed from 2 to 3 and for 'Bob' both columns changed.

My question is - what is the most idiomatic way to extract the pairs (`Name`, `Column(s)`) for each such change? It doesn't matter even what are the actual values changed, only their corresponding rows and columns.

I would like to write a function that behaves like this:

```py
updated = check_for_updates(df1, df2)
print(updated)
# [
#   ("John", ("Value1",)),
#   ("Sue", ("Value2",)),
#   ("Bob", ("Value1", "Value2")),
# ]
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: sure thing, I added the third row with both columns changed as well to better illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas 1.1 offers a way to [compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html#pandas.DataFrame.compare) dataframes; you can extend it further with a `defaultdict` to fit your end result :

```
from collections import defaultdict

updated = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in (df1
                   .set_index("Name")
                   .compare(df2.set_index("Name"), keep_shape=True)
                   .stack(0).index):
    updated[key].append(value)

print(updated)

defaultdict(list,
            {'John': ['Value1'],
             'Sue': ['Value2'],
             'Bob': ['Value1', 'Value2']})
```

Comment: Great stuff, looks like exactly what I was going for. Time to update the pandas version then :D

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try `df1.set_index('Name')` and `df2.set_index('Name')` it would be possiblr to do what you want. I mean then you can extract using their name

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and I'm pretty satisfied with this solution:

```py
df1 = DataFrame(data={"Name": ["John", "Sue", "Bob"], "Value1": [1, 1, 1], "Value2": [2, 2, 2]})
df2 = DataFrame(data={"Name": ["John", "Sue", "Bob"], "Value1": [4, 1, 5], "Value2": [2, 3, 6]})

def check_for_updates(df1, df2, columns, index):
  result = df2[df1[columns] != df2[columns]].dropna(how="all") # unchanged rows do not interest me
  result[index] = df1[index]

  return [(_id, tuple(cols.dropna().index)) for _id, cols in result.set_index(index).iterrows()]

updated = check_for_updates(df1, df2, columns=["Value1", "Value2"], index="Name")
print(updated)
# [
#   ('John', ('Value1',)),
#   ('Sue', ('Value2',)),
#   ('Bob', ('Value1', 'Value2'))
# ]
```

However I'm feeling (not being that much familiar with pandas) that there's a better way to do this, so feel free to correct me.

Edit: While writing this answer, @sammywemmy posted an alternative, which is in my opinion slightly more idiomatic.